# Extending DAO with JDBCDAOSupport, a bad practice?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

i have seen a lot of examples on the internet and in real life. That people extend their DAO with JDBCDaoSupport while using Spring framework. It is conceptually very much wrong as extends or inheritance is an "is a" relationship. While our DAO is DAO it is not DAOSupport of whatever kind. By Extending it with JDBCDaoSupport we make it a JDBCDaoSupport. If someone wants to use JDBCDaoSupport he should use it by composition not by inheritance. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not referring to Spring's [JdbcDaoSupport](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/support/JdbcDaoSupport.html)?

From the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/support/JdbcDaoSupport.html):

> Convenient super class for JDBC-based data access objects. Requires a
>   DataSource to be set, providing a JdbcTemplate based on it to
>   subclasses through the getJdbcTemplate() method.

In terms of implementation decision why JdbcDaoSupport is using internally inheritance rather than composition that's because DaoSupport is an abstract class. This is textbook inheritance since DaoSupport serves as a skeletal support implementation to be subclassed by Jdbc/Hibernate/Cci DaoSupport classes.

In terms of why we are extending our Daos from JdbcDaoSupport rather than using composition that's so we can get `getJdbcTemplate()` or `getDataSource()` directly rather than having to create our own infrastructure to expose them. In such case we don't need such support class from Spring since our Dao implementations are in a sense doing all the work. These *DaoSupport classes offered by spring are a very thin support layer to our Daos.

I would approach 'composition or inheritance' choice with a critical mind as there are legitimate cases where each approach fits best.

Comment: your phrases: "i have seen a lot of examples on the internet and in real life. That people extend their DAO with JDBCDaoSupport while using Spring framework" doesn't show you realise that JdbcDaoSupport is part of the Spring library. Assuming you do realise that then you question is about the architectural decision why JdbcDaoSupport is using inheritance and not composition. If you look at the code, JdbcDaoSupport is extending DaoSupport that is an abstract class

Comment: I've added to my answer as to why this has been chosen as an implementation decision

Comment: dear i am not asking why jdbcDaoSupport is extending DaoSupport. i am asking why developers extend their Dao with a DaoSupport? either it is JDBCDaoSupport or HibernateDaoSupport.

Comment: So that they can call "getJdbcTemplate()" or "getDataSource()" directly rather than having their own infrastructure exposing them if it was composition! If it was meant to be used with composition then there is no purpose of this Support class since all our Dao implementions are in essence serving the same purpose